# Cannot set local Tex path on ubuntu with "vanilla" TeX Live

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, paths

Using manual installation of TeX Live on Ubuntu (i.e. not via repos) I cannot seem to get LaTeX to look through my local tex directory path.
I've set TEXMFHOME using `sudo tlmgr conf texmf TEXMFHOME "~/.texlive2014"` and running `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME` gives:
"/home/angel/.texlive2014/".

I also ran `texhash ~/.texlive2014/` and it produced a correct `ls-R` file.
Under `~/.texlive2014/` I have several directories with BIB and STY files.

Still, local packages and styles are not found when I try to compile documents. Needless to say, linking the required style files to the directory where the LaTeX doc is works.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You shouldn't have a `ls-R` file in `TEXMFHOME`.

Comment: Why not? So I shouldn't run `texhash` for the `$TEXMFHOME` dir? Well anyway, even before I ran it didn't work.

Comment: are the files in your TEXMFHOME in TDS structure? I.e., tex/latex/... and bibtex/bib/.... ? TEXMFHOME is a normal tree thathas to be in standard layout! PS: remove ls-R, not needed!

Comment: No it's not. I didn't know it was necessary and I'm also not entirely sure how to construct it for the various file types (e.g. sty, bbx, cbx etc.). If ls-R isn't needed does that mean that also running `texhash` isn't needed?

Comment: No ls-R needed, no texhash needed. But TDS structure is absolutely needed. You can see the search path by typing kpsewhich -show-path .sty, then you should know whereto put. Or look into any shipped TDS tree (texmf-dist) for examples!

Comment: Ok got it working. So the path needs to be `~/.texlive2014/texmf-var/tex/latex/` but beyond that the files can be in any structure.
Good to know!

Comment: @norbert why didn't you publish it as an answer?

Comment: @RoeyAngel done now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Handling of TEXMFHOME

Here are some points how to set up your `TEXMFHOME` in a way that all the TeX related programs, i.e., those using the kpathsea library, will fine the proper files:

- TEXMFHOME is normally in `~/texmf`, but can be changed to anything else if required
- don't use `ls-R` files, don't run `texhash` or `mktexlsr` on `TEXFMHOME`
- `TEXMFHOME` has to be in [TeX Directory Structure TDS](http://tug.ctan.org/tds/tds.html) format, most basically this means that input files for LaTeX have to go in `TEXMFHOME/tex/latex` or below, fonts (`tfm`, `map`, etc) into `TEXMFHOME/fonts/tfm` etc.

Tips to debug:

- use `kpsewhich -show-path .sty` to get an idea where files are searched for
- use `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` to find out the location that is used for your setup, and check whether your changes did work out

Hope that helps.